# Remove padding between cards in recycler view grid layout manager

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-recyclerview

I have a card view in a recycler view with grid layout manager. I want to remove the space between the cards but also keep the specific width of the cards.

Here my layout activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".Catalog"
android:id="@+id/content_mainfragment">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my card:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="350dp"
android:layout_height="315dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="@color/primaryLightColor"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/card_Title"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
  ....
    ...
    ....
```

[image]

Comment: You can change the padding of the root layout where your `CardView` is located, and that will change the padding between the cards

Comment: No tried that doesnt work

Comment: need to see more XML than this...

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: your card width is set to android:layout_width="350dp".... this is why. make that match_parent

Comment: I put it to match parent card will be stretched. I want to have specific width.

Comment: but you dont want the space between them? you cant have both. unless you have three columns, not three. if you dont want the space between them, then you have to make it match parent. if you dont want that to stretch like that, then make then gravity center... if you dont want that then make three columns.... if u dont want that, then give up. haha

Comment: Where can i put the gravity center?

Comment: probably in the gridview tag

Comment: There is no gridview tag. I said im using the grig layout manager. It hasnt have any tags nor its an xml. I think you dont know what this question is for.

Comment: then, make the main layout match_parent, put the remainer contents in a relativelayout that is 350dp...and make the cardviews gravity center.

Comment: Updated my picture and xml. The space between them is still there.

Comment: i knew it would be still there.... i said that. you have it HARD CODED to be a specific width....

Comment: if device is landscape...make three columns... else 1 (portrait)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cardview width and height to fulfill your requirements. See the below code to know more.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_raw_visit_comments_receiver"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/scale_100dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/scale_100dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="3dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_raw_relative"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/text_raw_company_grid_menu"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_raw_company_profile_menu"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/text_raw_company_grid_menu"
                    android:textColor="@color/grid_menu_text_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_11"
                    tools:text="Task"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```